# How can i pass data between swipe tab fragment?

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-fragments, tabs

I am create an application that pass data between Swipe tab fragments for example in my first tab i create a listview i want to touch one item of list and change to my second tab if i touch another item in my first tab i want to my second tab changes to the specific content that i touch in my listview. i try this but my application closes.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int posicion,long id) {
        String _grade = _Adapterprimaria.getItem(posicion);

        switch(posicion){
        case 0:
            Bundle _Tap = new Bundle();
            _Tap.putSerializable("grade", _grade);
            Intent _intent = new Intent(Fragment_A.this.getActivity(),Fragment_B.class);
            _intent.putExtras(_Tap);
            startActivityForResult(_intent,0);
            break;
        }

    }
```

But when i touch an item my application closes, how can i pass data between fragments and change to first swipe tab fragment to second swipe tab fragment

Comment: Somebody help me!!!! :(

Comment: You have to use FragmentManager like this

    SecondFragment secFrag = new SecondFragment();
    FragmentTransaction fragTransaction =         getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragTransaction.replace(R.id.FRAME_LAYOUTID,secFrag );
                    fragTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragTransaction.commit();

Comment: @NadeemIqbal i do this
Fragment_B segundoFragment = new Fragment_B();
   android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaccion = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
   transaccion.replace(R.layout.fragment_b, segundoFragment);
   transaccion.addToBackStack(null);
   transaccion.commit();

But it doesnt work i do this in my method onItemclick